# extension app id is not available

Tags: ios

My app id is `com.company.app`, and my extension app id is `com.company.app.extension`.

I have created the provisioning profiles. When I upload to app store, failed with the tip

> an app id with identifier 'com.company.app.extension' is not available. Please enter a different string.

How to fix it?

Comment: Have you created 2 provisioning profiles for the two?

Comment: Yes, I have created 2 provisioning profiles for them.

Comment: @childrenOurFuture  do you meet this problem?

Comment: Not yet, just some setting or configure has a little mistake, I guess, but I am unable to point out.

Comment: @childrenOurFuture Ok, thank you!

Comment: Create provisioning profile with com.company.app

use that provisioning profile for Both Parent App and Extension